# I am new to Python and getting this error while creating new Python 2 notebook. The Error is "Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb".

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am learning python and Installed Anaconda and Trying to generate new python 2 notebook using jupyter notebook. I am using windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check If your "Untitled.ipynb” is open or in use somewhere in system.If yes close it.